# Any statistical test to get the understanding of data - Does higher price leads to better quality?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I have got following dataset. Price (3: highest); Quality Rating (4:best,0:pathetic); obs (number of people that gave the given rating for a given level of price)

Questions:

I want to check my hypothesis that price is linked to rating positively. Which test will give that result to me?

What are the good visualizations that I can create out of this one using Python

Data can be taken from following link as below data may not come in correct format

http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/pricequal.dat

```
price   rating  obs
```

0   3   0   4
1   2   0   1
2   1   0   4
3   3   1   8
4   2   1   21
5   1   1   20
6   3   2   26
7   2   2   22
8   1   2   23
9   3   3   15
10  2   3   12
11  1   3   9
12  3   4   7
13  2   4   4
14  1   4   4

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. People start to downvote your question because it is a bit vague, and asks multiple questions at the same time which is discouraged here. Please supply a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do you have a data example? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to assess whether `price` correlates to `rating`. There are many statistical methods to assess correlation, and you might be better off searching [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) in this regard.

Since you seem to have "categorical" data (i.e., ratings are in categories not on a continuous scale), I would recommend using [Spearman's rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_correlation). The resulting r value describes how well the two variables correlate to one another.

In python you could achieve this with:

```py
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

p, r = spearmanr(x, y)  # x and y are your data
```

To know "how much does rating increase based on price" you would need to look into predictive models such as linear regression.